# ASP.Net usage of the Machine.config file

Tags: encryption, asp.net, configuration

In ASP.Net, the normal way of encrypting an object ( as an exmaple a user cookie in the server side ) is read the shared key located in the machine.config file. The machine config file contains following config entries.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <machineKey decryptionKey="section for decryption key"
        validationKey="section for validation key" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Is this fully safe to use and safe to store key values like this? If not what are the other alternatives we have ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this fully safe to use and safe to store key values like this?

It is not a good idea to save your symmetric keys in a machine level config file. Main thing is , it can be accessed by any admin level user in your system and it is not private to your application only. This key in the config file is in plain text which is pretty bad in terms of security stand point.

Apart from that in a Web farm situation you need to replicate these keys in every host machine you are using. Hence, the key rotation and updates will also become a problem.

> If not what are the other alternatives we have ?

The best way to secure your symmetric keys in a server is by using a secure key store or a HSM ( Hardware Security Module).

Since you are using the .Net you can take  look at the [Data Protection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-use-data-protection) in .Net. If you are using the .Net Core the best way to deal with this is using the [Data Protection API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/using-data-protection) .

If you are deploying your application in a cloud environment like Azure, Then you can use [Azure Key vault](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/) .

[More Reading](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToKeepYourASPNETDatabaseConnectionStringsSecureWhenDeployingToAzureFromSource.aspx)